What does USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING do in Hetzner installimage conf?
When I order a new server, SSH into it (while it is running the initial network-booted rescue system) and run installimage, text editor will open where I am supposed to specify the new system configuration. For example:
DRIVE1 /dev/nvme0n1
DRIVE2 /dev/nvme1n1
SWRAID 1
SWRAIDLEVEL 1
HOSTNAME myserver.example.net
USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING yes
PART /boot     ext3 1024M
PART /boot/efi esp  256M
PART lvm       vg0  all
LV vg0   root   /        xfs         25G
LV vg0   swap   swap     swap        32G
IMAGE /root/.oldroot/nfs/install/../images/Debian-1205-bookworm-amd64-base.tar.gz

What does USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING yes do?

From searching USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING in installimage repository it looks like when USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING is 0 an Linux boot option nomodeset is set:
installimage/debian.sh:
  # set linux_default in grub
  local grub_linux_default=''
  (( USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING == 0 )) && grub_linux_default+='nomodeset '
  grub_linux_default+="consoleblank=0"
  if is_virtual_machine; then
     grub_linux_default="${grub_linux_default} elevator=noop"
  fi

What does nomodeset do? There is an answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do

The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into the kernel. So all the programming of the hardware specific clock rates and registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than in the X driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to have high resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker free transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on some cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black screen. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

So if USE_KERNEL_MODE_SETTING yes is specified in installimage.conf, nomodeset is not set and Linux kernel will be managing video mode setting.
